# When I parsed with jsoup, the contents of the tag disappeared

Tags: java, jsoup

I am studying jsoup library. And he was faced with difficulties. The tag seen in the Chrome developer tool disappears when parsed. Help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srMUp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfbam.png)

The contents of the  div  tag with an id called cbox_module are missing. Tell me how to get the contents of this tag.

and this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = "https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=597447&no=364&weekday=sat";
    String address = "https://comic.naver.com/comment/comment.nhn?titleId=651673&no=514";
    
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(address).get();
    Elements el = doc.select("#cbox_module");
    
    System.out.println(doc);
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

I am sorry if my English was poor. I'm a foreigner and I'm using a translator.

Comment: What's the raw HTML that you parse?

Comment: I tried to parse the HTML of this address and get the comments. https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=597447&no=364&weekday=sat

Comment: provide a url and also checkout some of the other answers under the `[jsoup]` tag as I answered many recently with some description about how I do this... network tab is useful to view the contents of a given http request. Also can you provide the code you're attempting this with so far?

Comment: thanks for updating - will be easier to take a look now

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're looking to extract here but you're taking the `cbox_module` which is the very first element after the `<body>` tags.

Looking through the network tab in chrome tools, I can see a request to:

```
https://apis.naver.com/commentBox/cbox/web_naver_list_jsonp.json?ticket=comic&templateId=webtoon&pool=cbox3&_callback=jQuery112408278558406808354_1605604312744&lang=ko&country=KR&objectId=651673_514&categoryId=&pageSize=15&indexSize=10&groupId=&listType=OBJECT&pageType=default&page=1&initialize=true&userType=&useAltSort=true&replyPageSize=10&_=1605604312745
```

That returns the Json that populates the comments in the page which gives you more direct access to the data you probably want.

Most of the query params are in the initial html response received however one in particular is not... `_callback=jQuery112408278558406808354_1605604312744`

`1605604312744` - is a unix time stamp and easy enough to obtain using `int now = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)));`

`jQuery112408278558406808354` - this was tough to understand how this is being computed but, from the scripts:

```js
...
 n.extend({
        expando: "jQuery" + (m + Math.random()).replace(/\D/g, ""),
...
```

`.replace(/\D/g, "")` - remove all non-digits - so a random number.

`m` is `"1.12.4"` at the top of the script (the jQuery version in use, possibly)... so we end up with a random number appended to `1124 +`  `0.9999999...` (some random value) (remove the `.` since its a non-digit) and we get the random `_callback` parameter value (16 decimal places).

This comes from: https://comic.naver.com/aggregate/javascript/release/comic_comment_20201113103349.js

I tried with this but it did not work. So I'm a little stumped as to how its working. I saw a .toLowerCase somewhere and when I do that on the URL + query params I get a "partner not recognised" error... something clearly not quite right.

I'd try with `HtmlUnit` as it has support for Javascript - it may make this much simpler.